# When running tests in parallel how to write log to different files?

Tags: c#, logging, parallel-processing, automation

Fore my tests report I use Allure framework and it allows me to attach a file to a test. I also use SpecFlow so I want to attach a log file to each tests step. And Allure allows me to do it.

Yet, I cannot figure out how to do it in a proper way when my tests are run in parallel.

**So what I need is** to have log per each test written to a file that I can handle independently from other log files ***from tests that run in parallel***.

Before I run tests in parallel I simply had a class like this:

```
public static class Log
{
    private static readonly string LogFileName = "testlog.json";

    public static bool IsFileExist => File.Exists(LogFileName);

    public static void WriteLine(string value)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(LogFileName, value);
    }

    public static string GetLogPath()
    {
        return LogFileName;
    }
}
```

Then I had a SpecFlow hook:

```
[AfterStep()]
public void AfterStep()
{
    if (Log.IsFileExist)
    {
        string logFilePath = Log.GetLogPath();

        AllureLifecycle.Instance.AddAttachment("displayedFileName", "application/json", logFilePath);

        //Clean log file 
        DeleteTestLogFile();
    }
}
```

So as soon as log file was attached to my report I removed it and it was created in the next step again.

Now, of-course when I run tests in parallel the file cannot be accessed from multiple threads.

How can I handle this? Maybe I use not good solution at all? If so, please advice a sufficient way to do what I want.

Comment: Use Log4Net.   Don’t reinvent the wheel

Comment: @MickyD thanks I'll try. But maybe you can provide an example as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to just use a lock on the code that writes to the file.

```
public static class Log
{
    private static readonly string LogFileName = "testlog.json";
    private static Object myLock = new Object();

    public static bool IsFileExist => File.Exists(LogFileName);

    public static void WriteLine(string value)
    {
        lock (myLock )
        {
            File.AppendAllText(LogFileName, value);
        }

    }

    public static string GetLogPath()
    {
        return LogFileName;
    }
}
```

If that ends up being a performance problem, you could try adding your logs to a ConcurrentQueue and having another thread monitoring it and writing to the actual file.

Comment: That might not work if the test runner uses multiple AppDomains

Comment: @bcwhims thanks, it helped with file locking but not if mixes logs from different tests to one file.

Comment: @DenisKoreyba do you mind sharing your solution? I'm running into the same challenge right now.